# AOV calculation in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the AOV calculation in Bigquery followed by cohorts without using a subquery to parse the dates...

```
select 
date_trunc(events, week), sum (purchase_revenue_in_usd)/count (distinct user_pseudo_id) as AOV
from (SELECT *, PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date) as events
     from `turing_data_analytics.raw_events`)
where event_date between '2020-11-01'and '2021-01-24'
group by 1
order by 1
```

can anyone help me?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the Average Order Value, you will have to divide the purchase revenue with the number of transactions.

```
sum(purchase_revenue_in_usd)/COUNTIF(event_name IN ('in_app_purchase', 'purchase'))
```

Your current SQL calculates the average revenue per user.